# Extract segment from shapely line interersecting polygon

Tags: python, geometry, line, shapely

I have several lines (`shapely.geometry.LineString`) and patches (`shapely.geometry.Polygon`). My goal is to find lines intersecting a set polygon (a patch). For the moment this works well but I get the entire list of coordinates of the line. **Instead I would like to get the two endpoints of the segment that effectively intersect the patch.**

The lines are indeed composed of two set of coordinates `x` and `y` that are lists of floats. They represent `[x1, x2, x3, ...]` and `[y1, y2, y3, ...]`. Below is a minimal working example to generate two lines and a patch that reproduces the data structure I use in my code (a big class too complex to copy and paste here).

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


intersections_list = []

x_line_patch =  [0, 4, -2, 8, 3, 10, 5]
y_line_patch =  [21, 17, 14, 11, 9, 6, 1]

x_line_patch2 =  [x + 20 for x in x_line_patch]
y_line_patch2 =  y_line_patch

# Create a patch
    
start_x = 5
end_x = 8
start_y = 5
end_y = 8

polygon = Polygon([(start_x, start_y), (end_x, start_y), (end_x, end_y), (start_x, end_y)])
lines = [LineString(zip(x_line_patch, y_line_patch)), LineString(zip(x_line_patch2, y_line_patch2))]

# Find line intersecting patches
patch_intersecting_lines = [line.xy for line in lines if line.intersects(polygon)]

# Extract the x and y coordinates of the polygon exterior
x, y = polygon.exterior.xy

# Plot the polygon
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.fill(x, y, alpha=0.3)  # Fill the polygon with color (optional)
# Plotting the line
x, y = lines[0].xy
x2, y2 = lines[1].xy
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x2, y2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Additionally, creating individual `LineString` for each set of `(x1, x2), (y1, y2)` would add complexity in a program that already uses a lot of loops and I don't have access to these lists of coordinates in reality. *They're defined here to construct a `LineString` object but are created later in the program when the lines are selected if they cross a patch. Otherwise I would just do:

```
line1 = [LineString(zip(x_line_patch[i:i+2], y_line_patch[i:i+2])) for i in range(0,len(x_line_patch)-1)]
```

to select coordinates 2 by 2 and create small segments for each line. But in my actual code I do `patch_intersecting_lines = [line.xy for line in lines if line.intersects(patch_shape)]` to find intersecting `line` given a list of lines called `lines`.

Comment: i think there's no way.. if you are concerned about code clearance i recommend creating a function for that task. But if the problem is creating a lot of sublines, you could first filter the whole path (as you do) then cutting the line in 2 parts recursively to find the current segment...

Comment: @UlisesBussi Do you mean cutting the path in half to find what part is inside the patch? Then to check if they intersect do you suggest using the same method `intersect` ?

Comment: yes. if path intersect, cut path in half ans check the first half, if intersects repeat if not, take the seccond half to intersect. this might be faster than create all the section if the number of sections is big...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I ended up doing several loop:

- First I grab all of the lines in my diagram
- Second, I generate a list of the lines intersecting my patch `[line for line in lines if line.intersects(patch_shape)]` and keep them as `LineString` objects
- Third, I iterate in this list to find all the segments of the line

```py
                    for line in patch_intersecting_lines:
                        x_line, y_line = line.xy
                        segments = [LineString(zip(x_line[i:i+2], y_line[i:i+2])) for i in range(0, len(x_line) - 1)]
```

- I then add the segment to `lines_intersecting` list if the segment is intersecting the patch or not (it can give a list of segments)

```py
segments_intersecting = [([self.voltage_to_coord_x(x) - patch_x for x in segment.xy[0]],
                                                  [self.voltage_to_coord_x(y) - patch_y for y in segment.xy[1]])
                                                 for segment in segments if segment.intersects(patch_shape)]
```

*I also calculate the coordinates accordingly because the patch and the line don't have same origin on the diagram (plot vs imshow problem).*

It feels overkill since I grab the line get the `x` and `y` but also re-use them to create the individual segments to then iterate again through the segments to finally return the `x` and `y` of said segment.

If you have a better suggestion that involves less loop I will gladly accept it.